# Removing values from an array that are close to eachother efficently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

I have a numpy array that has values like the following

```
[0.982555, 1.034195, 0.952625, 0.98255,  0.92392,  0.95262,  0.906955, 0.923915,
 0.868995, 0.90695,  0.777775, 0.803675, 0.80368,  0.82777,  0.828215, 0.86899,
 0.752685, 0.77777,  0.70911,  0.73267,  0.732965, 0.752675]
```

I want to remove the "duplicate" values however these values are not exactly the same, for example 0.77777 and 0.777775. Which one gets deleted doesn't matter, nor does the order of the array. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

I was thinking of using a standard deviation and a nested for loop but I was wanting something with better performance. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a better definition of close? Which values should you keep?

Comment: @DanielMesejo within 10% of the standard deviation should do it

Comment: If you first sort the values, then you can remove values based upon "closeness" in a single loop.

Comment: Adding on to @DarrylG if you sort, go to each one, see if the next one is equal or less than the current one plus 10% standard deviation, if so remove and move on to check the next until the next is not within that, then go to the next number and go again. You can move in a single direction.

Comment: can't you do something with [isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) numpy function?

Comment: A simple possibility is eg. `mean=arr.mean();std=arr.std();result=arr[np.abs(arr-mean)<std*0.1]`